# Emacs code for resizing frame

Tags: emacs

I've been writing some fortran code using emacs, and found that I needed emacs to recognise that the code I'm working on is fortran code (if for example your filename doesn't end in .f or .f90) so that the appropiate syntax highlighting is used. I found out that this can be done by including this comment at the beginning of the code:

```
! -*- mode: F90 -*-
```

I was wondering if there was something similar I could put at the beginning of the code which would cause the emacs frame to resize? It would be useful because I have a small input file which I open regularly for my simulations, and everytime I open it I need to resize its frame  to something smaller so that it fits snugly without wasting screen space. I still want the default frame size for other source code I'm working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `eval`:

```
! -*- eval: (set-frame-size (selected-frame) 40 25) -*-
```

Or the more general form:

```
! Local Variables: 
! eval: (set-frame-size (selected-frame) 40 25) 
! end:
```

Here is a description: http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables

Emacs asks you, if the code should be executed. Executing foreign code is a security problem. You can customize the behavior:

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-option`<kbd>Return</kbd>`enable-local-variables`<kbd>Return</kbd>

See the documentation here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/File-Local-Variables.html#File-Local-Variables

Comment: Thanks, that worked. One small question though. I tried setting enable-local-variables it to t, so that it would only ask me once, but it asks me everytime I open that file. So instead I've set enable-local-variable to :all so it doesn't ask me at all. Have I misunderstood how setting enable-local-variable to t works?

Comment: True sets only safe variables. But `eval` is not safe. If you set the option to `:all` you are in trouble, if you open evil files. Keep it `t` and answer the question with `!` to tell Emacs, that the use of `set-frame-size` is safe.